# Get the month of a year in android?

Tags: android

Can someone help me out in this.I need to find the month in words of a particular date in android.I am using the following code to get the day of the week(I have passed the parameters of the day.) by not understanding how to get the month.
This returns the day of the week :

```
public static String getFullDayName(int day_,int year_,int month_) 
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // date doesn't matter - it has to be a Monday
        // I new that first August 2011 is one ;-)
        c.set(year_, month_-1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        // c.set(2013,7,03);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day_-1);
        return String.format("%tA", c);
    }
```

I have tried the following code to get the month of the year but not getting the answer(month).but gives me the day of week instead.

Comment: this is perfect duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method as below

```
public static String getFullDayName(int day_,int year_,int month_) 
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // date doesn't matter - it has to be a Monday
        // I new that first August 2011 is one ;-)
        c.set(year_, month_-1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        // c.set(2013,7,03);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day_-1);

        // Option 1 
        // String month = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US); // Returns like August
        // Option 2 
        // String month = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US); // Returns like Aug      

        // And other option can be      
        String month = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", c.getTime()); // Returns like Aug

        return month;
    }
```

Comment: Yes see `option 1` of my given answer or you can use `MMMM` instead of using 'MMM' into last option..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```